# $digest() iterations reached. Aborting! when getting Vimeo thumbnail within ngRepeat

Tags: angularjs, vimeo-api

I am trying to parse video URL and render thumbnail. It is working for YouTube(though I did not implement the API doc). If the video is from Vimeo, my browser is freezing or sometimes the thumbnail is blank. How can I get Vimeo video thumbnails within the ngRepeat?

Here is the plunker link:

http://plnkr.co/edit/R2yDwc4fjz1xBPiVCv60?p=preview

I commented out the Vimeo part to avoid freezing.

```
    $http.jsonp(("http://vimeo.com/api/v2/video/" + parsed.id + ".json?callback=JSON_CALLBACK&_=") + (new Date().getTime())).success(function(r) {
      _url = r.thumbnail_large
     }).error(function(e) {
       console.log(e);
     });
```

Answer (score 1):

Probably the cause of lagging is too much requests inside of an ngRepeat. Better strategy in that case is to prepare your data upfront and use repeat only to display it:

```
// first prepare 
$scope.properties = $scope.properties.map(function (prop) {
  prop.thumbnail = VideoParser.getThumbNail(prop.video);
  return prop;
})

// then in html just use <img ng-src='{{ prop.thumbnail }}'>
```

Also it worth to check out if Vimeo API allows to get a set of thumbnails instead of querying them one-by-one.

Comment: My browser is still freezing and getting this error $digest() iterations reached. Aborting!

Comment: The error can be somewhere else. You can try to set thumb to a constant inside map `prop.thumbnail = 'some image';` and run app to see if it fails because of queries to Vimeo API.

Comment: As stated above, confirmed that it's the query to Vimeo API is causing the issue.

Comment: Ok, I see another issue - `_url` is being set asyncronosly and hence it's returned before the `$http.jsonp` callback is executed. Use promise to get the value returned from jsonp

Comment: On your place I'd better move this functionality to the back-end. As many parallel queries will freeze browser UI anyway. Is it feasible in your setup?

Comment: Yes and that's what I did, move the thumbnail to back-end. I hope there is an answer or proper way to handle it on the front-end.